# How to resolve the canvas-prebuilt Node.js version incompatibility issue?

Tags: node.js, canvas

I am trying to use `canvas-prebuilt` in my project.

Here is the list of dependency in `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas-prebuilt": "^1.6.5-prerelease.1",
    "canvas-to-image-node": "^1.0.4",
    "wordcloud": "^1.0.6"
  },
```

But I encountered this error:

```
module.js:653
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:653:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
```

So I tried this command `npm rebuild`. And I got this error:

```
> canvas-prebuilt@1.6.5-prerelease.1 install /Users/antkong/test/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt
> node-pre-gyp install

[canvas-prebuilt] Success: "/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt/canvas/build/Release/canvas-prebuilt.node" is installed via remote

> canvas@1.6.7 install /Users/antkong/test/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 522 status code downloading checksum
```

How can I fix this issue?

One solution I am contemplating is to downgrade the nodejs to `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57`.  However I don't which nodejs version correspond to `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57`. My node version is currently 8.7.0

```
$ node --version
v8.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is a tricky that package a compatible node.exe in the deployment to make it self-contained.
And add a script to insert current folder at the head of PATH environment variable to ignore the node in target env.
I'm using windows.